# Ubuntu Trusty not showing "System restart required" on first login after unattended-upgrades

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pam

I'm running ubuntu 14.04.3 with unattended-upgrades configured to install security updates only.

This works as expected, with email notifications as follows when a reboot is required:

```
Unattended upgrade returned: True

Warning: A reboot is required to complete this upgrade.
```

The puzzling thing is that when I log in via ssh to perform the reboot, I would expect the login banner to also tell me that a restart is required, but it doesn't, I just get:

```
42 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

However, if I immediately log out and log in again, *then* I get:

```
42 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

*** System restart required ***
```

I realise that these login messages are being generated by `pam_motd`, and the (default) configuration in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` is as follows:

```
session    optional    pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
session    optional    pam_motd.so # [1]
```

It seems that the file `/run/motd.dynamic` is only being updated *after* the login processing is completed the first time, but why is it configured this way (`noupdate`) by default?  What is the purpose of the second line for pam_motd.so in the conf file?  The comment `[1]` looks like it should refer to a footnote, but there is no such note in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug.  The Debian sshd pam configuration was changed to add `noupdate` to the first line, which displays the file `/run/motd.dynamic`, on [21 May 2012](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/loggerhead/pkg-ssh/openssh/trunk/revision/3507/debian/openssh-server.sshd.pam), to prevent the motd update scripts being run twice.  It should have been added to the second line, which displays the static `/etc/motd` (if it exists).  This was corrected in the source code on [05 Aug 2014](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-ssh/openssh.git/commit/debian/openssh-server.sshd.pam.in?id=e61f7c4d94f348cb172e595f2e8a09c7ed201510).

I still don't know what the comments `[1]` in the config file are supposed to mean, but they were already there when the source file `debian/ssh.pam` was first added to the openssh-server package on 01 Sep 2003.